# midi | How do I tell when the string sound is Pizzicato (A sort of finger-pinch noise)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, audio, midi

first thing - Pizzicato means that you sort of pinch the violin/cello/bass with your fingers and you get more of a guitar-pinching noise instead of a regular violin.

When I convert the midi to mp3 using a random program - the program makes this pizzicato just fine (since I hear it). but when I am trying to look for a hint when does this pizzicato accure when I am trying to read the midi file myself (using midi-to-as3 library in flash) I only get these instruments type:

> String Ensemble
>
> String Ensemble

No indication for this different noise - where is this data stores?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you can playback any MIDI file through [MIDI-OX](http://www.midiox.com/) and see exactly what messages are being sent.

Second, there is no specific MIDI message for this.  What you are hearing is the result of short notes with likely large velocity.  The synth generating the sound for strings is programmed to respond in this way.

You should also know that you can't really rely on the synth generating the proper pizz sound you are looking for.  They all generate sounds in different ways, and the sound is not actually defined by MIDI.  The instruments you see listed are [General MIDI](http://www.midi.org/techspecs/gm1sound.php), but the synth can do whatever it wants.

Comment: velocity = volume? or can it be equal to other things?

Comment: It can be equal to whatever the synth wants it to be.  Usually it is mapped to volume and sound of the attack of the note.  Velocity is just the name of the MIDI parameter in the note on/off message.  It is named this way as MIDI was originally defined for keyboard instruments.  Keyboards generally map the velocity at which you strike keys to the velocity parameter.  (But again, this can be redefined!)